# How to put button on top of image? (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I put button  over the image and keep it in the center of the window? The code works fine but the button is under the image and I cannot click it

```
from tkinter import Frame, Tk, Label, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)

        self.image = Image.open("folder\\file.gif")
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill="both", expand="YES")
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry("600x600")
root.configure(background="black")

e = Example(root)
e.pack(fill="both", expand="YES")

btn=Button(root,text="Hello World").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You cannot overlap widgets using `.pack()`.  You can use `.grid()` (place them both in the same row/column), or `.place()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right solution for your real app, but for the code in the question the simplest solution is to use `place`. With `place` you can use relative placement to keep a widget centered in another widget.

`place` is not the best too as a general purpose layout manager, but for very specific use cases it's the right tool for the job. In the following example, the button is placed in the center of the `Example` frame by using `relx`, `rely`, and `anchor`. The `in_` parameter specifies which widget the relative coordinates are relative to.

```
btn=Button(root,text="Hello World")
btn.place(in_=e, relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")
```